# Call order after starting a programm

Tags: java, inheritance, static, instance

Can anybody explain to me the order of the output? Especially, what the "this(D()1" in the constructor causes?
Are there some "rules" ijn which order which variable is declared? (static/instance and so on)

Sorry for my bad english.

[image]

Comment: can you post the output?

Answer (score 0):

A `Java` program executes from the top down in the `main()`-method. From there it does whatever the code tells it to do. In your case, it can be summarized as follows:

1. Prints the line to console.
2. When creating a new Dog, its superclass (`Mammal`) must first be created. The `this("D(2)")` calls the other constructor of class `Dog`.
3. From there the superclass `Mammal` is instantiated, since it extends `DomesticAnimal`, that must be created first. and since the variable `da` is declared to be initialized outside the constructor, it is done first.
4. The constructor completes and prints the line.
5. The rest of `Mammal` is instantiated, same as in (3)
6. The line is printed after the super class is successfully instantiated. Same as (4)
7. With all super classes created, class `Dog`'s attribute outside the constructor is initialized. Same as in (5) and (3).
8. Line is printed. Same as (6) and (4)
9. The other constructor method has competed, so the rest of the initially called constructor executes. I.e. the line is printed.